# scatterplots within a certain range - python

Tags: python, range, scatter-plot

In essence, I need to make a square scatterplot from (0,1) to (0,1). The points within the quarter-circle centered at the origin need to be colored red, and the ones outside need to be colored blue. The way I was planning to do it was to make 2 scatterplots on the same graph, one with y1 = the range under the quarter-circle, and one with y2 = the range above the quarter-circle.

**This is what I have so far:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(500)
y1 < np.sqrt(1-x**2)
y2 > np.sqrt(1-x**2)

plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)

c1 = 'r'
c2 = 'b'
plt.scatter(x, y1, c=c1, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.scatter(x, y2, c=c2, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.axes().set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

This code gives me [this plot,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNTl3.png) when I should be getting [something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3iDU.png) If someone could tell me how to fix my y1 and y2 values, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closer look at

```
y1 < np.sqrt(1-x**2)
y2 > np.sqrt(1-x**2)
```

... these two lines only give you boolean arrays. The code you posted actually gives you an error, which makes clear, you never saved y1 and y2.

So you rather should:

```
x = np.random.random(500)
y = np.sqrt(1-np.random.random(500)**2)
x1 = x[y<x]
y1 = y[y<x]
...
```

PS: adapted, now x and y are not directly correlated any more, corresponding to comments

Comment: you should take y1 from y. 
@alexs683 - do that (with the fix) for x1, y1 and correspondly to x2 y2, then use `plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=c1, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=c2, cmap=plt.cm.jet)`

Comment: That was something that I had originally, but setting y-val to equal sqrt(1-x^2) only gives me the outline of the quarter circle. I need to have the scatterpoints to be different colors below and above the boundary. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @alex683 you should use random y values above or beyond the outline

Comment: `x1 = x[y<x]
y1 = y[y<x]

x2 = x[y>x]
y2 = y[y>x]

plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)

c1 = 'r'
c2 = 'b'
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=c1, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=c2, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
` So this is the version I tried, which gives me the 500 points on the outline of the circle again, and not below or above. Am I missing something?

Comment: tried the newest ^ solution with `y = np.sqrt(1-np.random.random(500)**2)`. The scatterplots are now below and above the line, which is nice - but the line is not a circle, but rather a straight line from (0,0) to (1,1). How can I fix the `x1 = x[y<x]` part of the code to represent the quarter - circle? And could you explain what the code is doing at that point? Thanks so much

Comment: This is rather a mathematical problem: you want something like x^2 + y^2 < 1 (red) and x^2 + y^2 > 2 (blue)

Answer (score 0):

IMO your approach doesn't quite get the point of the (assumed) topic. Afaics this is about calculating `pi` by the ratio of randomly distributed points in a (quarter) circle and its square.

The point is here to not calculate the points coordinates in any way, but to let them be distributed completely randomly. And afterwards, you can go and decide to plot this in whatever color you want with whatever underlying rule or algorithm.
Short, this would be my approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(500)
y = np.random.random(500)

plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)

c = np.where(x**2 + y**2 < 1, 'r', 'b')

plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)

plt.gca().set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

for completeness an example of the assumed topic:

```
for i in range(1,9):
    x = np.random.random(10**i)
    y = np.random.random(10**i)
    d = np.where(x**2 + y**2 < 1, 1, 0)
    print(f'{10**i:>9} points: {4*np.sum(d)/d.size}')

#        10 points: 2.8
#       100 points: 3.08
#      1000 points: 3.076
#     10000 points: 3.1556
#    100000 points: 3.14456
#   1000000 points: 3.141884
#  10000000 points: 3.142634
# 100000000 points: 3.14158668
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Originally that's what I wanted to do but wasn't sure how to implement, so I ended up trying the 2 different plots method. I think this method is more elegant anyways.